# startActivity(intent) and onStop

Tags: android, android-intent, android-lifecycle

I have a problem concerning startActivity(intent) and onStop.  The Android API suggests to save data in onStop, which is what I am doing here:

```
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();

    if(tosave)
    {
        Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putInt(getString(R.string.index_of_text_color), text_color_index);
        editor.putInt(getString(R.string.index_of_background_color), background_color_index);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

However, I would like to start the next activity once it is saved- so I need to use an intent and startActivity(intent).

```
public void click(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

My question is, does startActivity(intent) with the two flags call the onStop() method as it is finishing the application, or do I need to call finish()?  Is it allowed for me to call finish() after I start a new activity?  Or, is it because the new activity will be at the top, Android automatically calls onStop as it is in the background now?

There are so many questions about how startActivity(intent) works with the app cycle that I do not understand.  It will be helpful if someone points me to a link.

Thank you!

EDIT: the intent is not in onStop.  It is in another method which corresponds to a button.  As soon as the button is clicked, I will need to save the data-- go to onstop-- and then go to the next activity.  How can I do that?

Comment: onStop is called when your activity is completely obscured. Starting a new Activity in that state seems like really bad idea, because usually the reason for your activity to be obscured is that another activity is started! I hope it throws an Exception if you try that.

Answer (score 0):

You should save state in `onPause()`, not `onStop()`, because under certain conditions `onStop()` will never be called. You are guaranteed that `onPause()` will be called.

`onPause()` will always be called on your activity when another activity is shown in front of it.

That should solve your problem.

Comment: When I call startActivity(intent) will the application still calls onpause...and do I need finish() afterwards? Also onPause is not supposed to handle stuff that requires too much cpu, like saving data.. but I guess this will work

Comment: You shouldn't do too much stuff in `onPause()`. What are you trying to do there? From which component are you calling `startActivity()`? You need to call `finish()` on activities that you want to explicitly finish. I think you need to read more about activity lifecycles. Please explain your problem more completely and provide more code.

Comment: I did not do anything with `onPause()`.  `startActivity(intent)` is called from the `android:onClick` in xml to the method `click` as mentioned.  I do not know if I need to put `finish()` in the click method.  The intent is set so that there will be no stacks left in the application once the other is open, so I do not know if I need to call `finish()`

Comment: If the `Intent` is clearing the activity off the stack, then it will call `finish()` on the activity for you. You don't need to do it.

Comment: You don't need to use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` if this is opening an activity in the same task.

Comment: I am not opening the same activity- I am calling another activity.

Comment: Yes, I know. But this is in the same task. So you don't need `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. You also probably need to read up about the difference between activities, tasks, processes and applications.